# PHP Drop Down List Populated By Oracle Database Rows

Tags: php, oracle10g

I'm getting an empty drop down list while trying to populate it with values from an Oracle 10G website.

The drop down list appears, but there are no values inside of it. I also have error reporting on, but am not getting any errors.

Can anyone point out my error?

```
<tr>
  <td>Unit List</td>
    <td>
      <select name="unit">
          <?php 
              $conn = oci_connect("user", "password", "db");
              $sql = 'select ORGANIZATION_NAME from organization@something';
              $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
              while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC))
              {
                  echo "<option value=\"unit1\">" . $row['ORGANIZATION_NAME'] . "</option>";
              }
          ?>
      </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is first? Syntax? Unexpected output? You need to form a complete problem statement please.

Comment: @thatidiotguy, that's what's weird. I have error reporting on, but I'm not getting anything, it's just populating at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing the query, after parsing the query you need to execute it before fetching the results, the function you need is [`oci_execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php), used like this:

```
$success = oci_execute($stid)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. For some reason I thought just calling "oci_fetch_array" would execute it.